# How do I code an ID number whose first digit changes depending on the subclass created?

Tags: java, oop, polymorphism, abstract-class

I'm working on an assignment in my computer science course and I am stuck on a certain part where I'm asked to generate ID numbers with specific rules and I am not sure how to go about it. Here are the exact instructions:

**Phase 3: Item
Items are used in the system as a superclass for both Flight and Payloads. All Items are issued a unique identifier
within the system, for tracking. The rules for IDs are as follows:
• All ID numbers are 9 digits long
• The first digit changes based on the type of item
o Commercial Flights start with 1
o Industrial Flights start with 2
o Persons start with 3
o Cargo starts with 4
• The last 8 digits begin at 0 and increase by one for each item created
o That is, the first Item created will end in 0, the next will end in 1, and so on. Example: creating a
Commercial flight would be issued id 100000000, then a Person would be issued 300000001
respectively.
Consider where to add code in the hierarchy (Item, and its subclasses) to generate and store these IDs.**

This is the code I tried, the class Item and its constructor:

```
public abstract class Item {
   protected int id;

   public Item() {
         int commercialID = 100000000;
         int industrialID = 200000000;
      if( this instanceof Commercial){
         id = commercialID;
         commercialID++;
  } else if (this instanceof Industrial) {
     id = industrialID;
     industrialID++;
  }
```

}

I also tried making the id variable static but that changed nothing
Here are Commercial and Industrial too

```
public class Industrial extends Flight{

    public Industrial(){
        super();
    }
}
```

```
public class Commercial extends Flight{

    public Commercial(){
        super();

    }
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: you can use a static variable to keep track of the last assigned item and combine that number with an offset for each subclass to generate your item id.

Answer (score 0):

You Item class is you top (abstract) class with 2 (abstract) subclasses: Payload and Flight

Item must define an abstract method that will return the offset in each concrete subclass.

Payload has 2 subclasses: Cargo and Person

Flight has 2 subclasses: CommercialFlight and IndustrialFlight

You must store the last generated id in a static field and increase it by one before to append it to the offset defined for each concrete class.

See example below:

```
public abstract class Item {
    protected int id;
    protected static int lastGeneratedId = 0;

    protected Item() {
        lastGeneratedId++;
        this.id = 100000000 * getIdPrefix() + lastGeneratedId;
        System.out.println(toString());
    }

    protected abstract int getIdPrefix();

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "New " + getClass().getName() + " created with id " + id;
    }
}
```

The two abstract sublasses:

**Flight**

```
public abstract class Flight extends Item {

    public Flight() {
        super();
    }
    
}
```

**Payload**

```
public abstract class Payload extends Item {

    public Payload() {
        super();
    }
    
}
```

And the concrete classes:

**CommercialFlight**

```
public class CommercialFlight extends Flight {
    
    public CommercialFlight() {
        super();
    }
    
    @Override
    protected  int getIdPrefix() {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

**IndustrialFlight**

```
public class IndustrialFlight extends Flight {
    
    public IndustrialFlight() {
        super();
        
    }
    
    @Override
    protected  int getIdPrefix() {
        return 2;
    }
}
```

**Person**

```
public class Person extends Payload {
    
    public Person() {
        super();
    }
    
    @Override
    protected  int getIdPrefix() {
        return 3;
    }
}
```

**Cargo**

```
public class Cargo extends Payload {
    
    public Cargo() {
        super();
    }
    
    @Override
    protected  int getIdPrefix() {
        return 4;
    }
}
```

And a class to test all this:

```
public class ItemTester {   
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Cargo();
        new IndustrialFlight();
        new Cargo();
        new CommercialFlight();
        new IndustrialFlight();
        new Person();
        new Person();
    }
}
```